# NUnit - repeating groups of tests under different conditions

Tags: unit-testing, nunit

I'm just getting into testing with NUnit and I've read advice in "the art of unit testing" about keeping tests self-contained and with a single path through the test code.

I've successfully used parameterized tests to create 10 tests for a function, but now I want to repeat those same tests under slightly different conditions - i.e. varying one variable which isn't a test parameter but using the same inputs and expecting the same results. If I wasn't using a test framework it would be a nested loop:

```
for each initial condition
    for each set of inputs
        run the test
    end loop
end loop
```

Obviously I could add "initial condition" as a test parameter but then I'd have 20 tests, whereas what I really want is 10 tests in condition A and then the same 10 in condition B. is there a recognized way of repeating tests in a more structured way so I don't have to list every combination?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking into [NUnit's TestCaseSource](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.5.9) and the TestCaseData class.

This allows you to provide a type that will be instantiated on each test run. From here, you could combine classes that provide the test data. I have seen this done successfully before with "Scenario" classes.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [NUnit Theory](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=theory&r=2.5):

- `Datapoint` and `Datapoints` would be the equivalent of *set of inputs*:

> **Data for Theories**
>
> The primary source of data for a Theory is the Datapoint or Datapoints
>   attribute. NUnit will use any fields of the required types, which are
>   annotated with one of these attributes, to provide data for each
>   parameter of the Theory. NUnit assembles the values for individual
>   arguments combinatorially to provide test cases for the theory.
>
> In addition to the Datapoint and Datapoints attributes, it is possible
>   to use any of the approaches for supplying data that are recognized on
>   normal parameterized tests. We suggest that this capability not be
>   overused, since it runs counter to the distinction between a test
>   based on examples and a theory. However, it may be useful in order to
>   guarantee that a specific test case is included.

- Assumptions would be the equivalent of an *initial condition*:

> **Assumptions**
>
> The theory itself is responsible for ensuring that all data supplied
>   meets its assumptions. It does this by use of the Assume.That(...)
>   construct, which works just like Assert.That(...) but does not cause a
>   failure. If the assumption is not satisfied for a particular test
>   case, that case returns an Inconclusive result, rather than a Success
>   or Failure.
>
> The overall result of executing a Theory over a set of test cases is
>   determined as follows:
>
> - If the assumptions are violated for all test cases, then the Theory itself is marked as a failure.
> - If any Assertion fails, the Theory itself fails.
> - If at least some cases pass the stated assumptions, and there are no assertion failures or exceptions, then the Theory passes.

Code example from NUnit website:

```
public class SqrtTests
{
    [Datapoint]
    public double zero = 0;

    [Datapoint]
    public double positive = 1;

    [Datapoint]
    public double negative = -1;

    [Datapoint]
    public double max = double.MaxValue;

    [Datapoint]
    public double infinity = double.PositiveInfinity;

    [Theory]
    public void SquareRootDefinition(double num)
    {
        Assume.That(num >= 0.0 && num < double.MaxValue);

        double sqrt = Math.Sqrt(num);

        Assert.That(sqrt >= 0.0);
        Assert.That(sqrt * sqrt, Is.EqualTo(num).Within(0.000001));
    }
}
```